# Avoid simultaneous modification of an object

Tags: c#, web

I'm building a web app, and so far i have build the CRUD for several database tables. 
Now, lets suppose that 2 users are using the app and both of them modify the same object but they are not aware of that.
So the first user that finish the modification of the object and expect certain state of that object but then the second user finish his modification and the object now will have the state that enter the second user.
How do i prevent this. Thanks

Comment: Add a concurrency stamp to you're object, when  saving see if the object has been updated since the original time the user requested the object, if it has been updated since then, do no allow the user to up date or give him an option to override the changes

Comment: Are you using entity framework? You can use do a simple diff on the objects (ie. isDirty for each field).  If there are no collisions, update with the changes from each user.   if there are collisions, do what @johnny5 said.  In the end it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Databases have generally support for that scenario out of the shelf. Azure Storage for instance support that using Optimistic Concurrency:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-concurrency

The way it works in Azure Storage tables (and blobs) is that azure assigns an ETag value to every entity. If you update the entity, azure updates the etag value on the entity, your second write request fails because it still has the old / not updated ETag value. You get a specific Http Status Code (412) and can handle that scenario on the client side in a deterministic way.

Clients can override this ETag check and make an unconditional write request if they want to. So the answer to your exact question depends on the underneath storage tech you are using.

I am just giving azure here as an example to explain how Optimistic (aka lock-free) concurrency works. Most modern databases provide a mechanism for handling concurrency so you should check the specifications of your underlying storage system (which you should have mentioned in your question to be more precise).

Comment: That's great...If you're using Azure.  Being that it's not tagged in the question, that very well may not be the case.

Comment: What about MySQL, does it have such mechanism?

Comment: You're better off doing what @johnny5 suggested.  Which is backend agnostic.

Comment: no definitely don't go blindly on trying to implement your own solution to concurrency without understanding your underlying storage technology, You will never be able to implement a 100% reliable concurrency solution on the client, by the time you check if the concurrency stamp is updated, some other client could update it and you will end up overriding that. I have not worked with MySql but I am sure they provide  a mechanism for concurrency albeit optimistic or pessimistic. It is a different question to keep things generic, you can still be generic while keeping specific adapters.